# What is the Maximum Size for an SD Card that the Pi 3 B?

Tags: sd-card, pi-3, storage, compatibility

I have an Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, I want to buy an SD Card for it. Are there any limits to the Maximum Size it can handle?

I wanted to buy an 128 GB Micro SDXC Card, but I heard that not all devices would be able to use them, So would the Raspberry Pi be able to handle it?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi FAQ Help says that they have tried to use 32 GB Cards and they worked.

> We have tried cards up to 32GB, and most cards seem to work OK. -[FAQ Site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#sdMax)-

For me, I have been using an Sandisk Extreme 32GB MicroSDHC Card and it has been working well. I just bought an 64 MicroSDXC Card for the Pi, and it seems to work as well.